# Windows 10 app provisioned to non-existent user

Tags: windows-10, wds, sysprep

I created an image of Windows 10 1709 and now I want to run sysprep so I can upload to WDS.  Sysprep fails:

> Package Microsoft.BingNews_4.21.2212.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe was installed for a user, but not provisioned for all users.

It shows it exists, but the user it references does not exist, thus I have no way to remove it from that user:

```
PackageFullName        : Microsoft.BingNews_4.21.2212.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
PackageUserInformation : {S-1-5-21-2431295864-3614308495-3179744271-1001
                         [S-1-5-21-2431295864-3614308495-3179744271-1001]: Installed}
```

The user does not have a profile and I even removed from the registry.

I tried to remove with *remove-appxpackage* but I'm told that the package was not found because the current user doesn't have it installed.

There is only the local admin account on the machine, and I did try installing Bing News and then trying sysprep, but the same error appeared.

How do I convince Windows of this?

Comment: Did you create your image while in audit mode? You cannot allow any apps to be provisioned or sysprep will fail.  Clicking on any of the apps will provision them. You use `remove-appxpackage` and `remove-provisonedappxpackage` to get rid of these.

Comment: How do I use those commands if the only user left on the system doesn't have them installed?  As mentioned in the OP, I tried those and it didn't work

Comment: Dont know what to say. Start over and do it in audit mode. It’s probably quicker. By the way, you didn’t mention you tried both commands - only one. So there is no way for me to know what you tried and if it is right. Post each command you used and the output.

Answer (score 0):

For Microsoft.BingNews_4.21.2212.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
And any package which sysprep complains just:

Remove-appxpackage -AllUsers

Example:

Remove-appxpackage -AllUsers Microsoft.BingNews_4.21.2212.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe

When you uninstall this one, a new one will appear, like this 20 more.
But if you go to C:\windows\system32\sysprep\panther\setupact.txt and copy the new package name that will appear.

Then repeat the Remove-appxpackage -AllUsers 
Until sysprep start to work.

I make it working after removing ~20 apps...